# git status - don't show untracked files

Tags: git, github, git-status

Is there an option to `git status` so that untracked files won't be shown?

I tried `git status -u no` but that hides everything and tells:

"nothing to commit, working directory clean"

even thouh there are files both staged for commit and not staged for commit.

I want it to show only files staged for commit and modified ones but skip untracked files.

Comment: This is what `.gitignore` is for.

Comment: Yes, obviously I need to modify .gitignore, I hate when `git status` spams my console with untracked files. thought there is a shortcut with command line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need:

```
git status -uno
```

i.e., without the space, or:

```
git status --untracked-files=no
```

Comment: Huh, I misread git documentation about `-u no`, thank you for quick response Paul! that works great.

Comment: @codekiddy: It's a bit of an unexpected format, for sure. `cmd -uno` would normally be equivalent to `cmd -u -n -o`, but git appears to take a different view.

Comment: Pro tip: All these options appear to do the same thing:`git status --untracked-files=no`, `git status --untracked-file=no`, `git status --untracked-fil=no`, `git status --untracked-fi=no`, `git status --untracked-f=no`, `git status --untracked=no`, `git status --untracke=no`, `git status --untrack=no`, `git status --untrac=no`, `git status --untra=no`, `git status --untr=no`, `git status --unt=no`, `git status --un=no`, `git status --u=no`.  ‍♂️